# How to filter data based on date range in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of location model which store booking info as an array of object.
I want to fetch only those data which is not in between the range of date store in bookings object.

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5bade0630c3a89206467f434"
},
"images": [
    "https://res.cloudinary.com/dfkmhdn1s/image/upload/v1538125214/cxaarsh4gvk83khg6deo.jpg"
],
"created_at": {
    "$date": "2018-09-28T07:56:11.485Z"
},
"name": "VX Resort",
"price": 856,
"address": "Nainital, Uttarakhand, India",
"zip": "244713",
"description": "Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.\r\n\r\nMorbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi, euismod in, pharetra a, ultricies in, diam. Sed arcu. Cras consequat.",
"owner": {
    "$oid": "5badc9c5104ac9287c37954b"
},
"bookings": [
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5bd935847f5eb301d822c42a"
        },
        "booking_from": {
            "$date": "2018-10-30T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "booking_to": {
            "$date": "2018-11-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
    }
],
"__v": 0
}
```

How to fetch only those record where the user selected date is not the same or not between "booking_from"  and "booking_to" dates store in **bookings** array.

**My Query**

```
db.getCollection('hostlocations').aggregate([
{ $match: {price:{$lte:900}} },
{ $project : { 
    "price" : "$$ROOT.price",
    "bookings" : "$$ROOT.bookings",
    "prefer" : "2018-10-31T00:00:00.000Z"
} },
{
    $match : {
        $or : [
            {"prefer": {$gt:"bookings.booking_from",$lt:"booking.booking_to"}},
            {"prefer": {$gte:"bookings.booking_from",$lt:"booking.booking_to"}},
            {"prefer": {$gt:"bookings.booking_from",$lte:"booking.booking_to"}},
        ]
    }
}
])
```

Comment: Could you show what you have tried yet

Comment: See question again please . I updated it with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check below aggregation:

```
db.getCollection('tests').aggregate([
    { $match: {
        price:{ $lte: 900 },
        $or: [
            { "bookings.booking_from": {$gt: ISODate("2018-10-30T00:00:00.000Z")}},
            { "bookings.booking_to": {$lt: ISODate("2018-10-30T00:00:00.000Z")}}
        ]}
    },
   { $project: { price: 1, bookings: 1 }}
])
```

Check working example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OcDxgGlsetc) with multiple data.